# Is it possible to verify if a website is vulnerable to SQLi by viewing its source code?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql, source-code, sql-server

I've heard the `eval()` function is vulnerable to SQLi.

Can I check for vulnerabilities by simply viewing the website source code?

Comment: Not the html generated server side and given to the client. If you got access tho the server side code (php/java/.net/asp) you could detect the SQLi vulnerabilities. That is a security code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "source code".

If you use the "view source" function in a web browser, that's not sufficient. That shows you the client side code, while SQLi occurs on the server side.

If you examine the full source code that is running on the server, then yes, examining it can let you find SQLi issues. You can even find SQLI by decompiling executable files if a system is using ASP without source files on the server but fails to protect the compiled files from download.

Answer (score 2):

The typical SQL injection attack can occur when the SQL command string is concatenated to include a user entry:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$user_name."'";
```

A malicious user could enter a user name like

> my name'; DROP TABLE users; --

Guess what happens!

---

Better [use prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/880990).

Comment: SQLi can also occur inside SQL procedures if they build up SQL statement the same way (by concatenating things, even when it's not direct user entries)

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` allow you to evaluate code, so yo can have a code injection. Example: `eval("echo 2;");` will print 2 in PHP.

In PHP you also have `shell_exec()` where you can execute shell commands.

You can check several types of injection [here](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/injection-attacks/).

Looking to the website source code is a valid way to check for links to other pages and check what query parameters are used. You can also check forms.

Another way is to check **Network** tab, to view what information is sent and received by your browser. Try to take a look into [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload), it will help you understand better how to intercept requests and tamper with them to check for some vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have access to the back-end source then yes, you'll be able to identify **SQLi**, but in another case nope, I always do it manually, testing all input parameters, for example filling username and password with **'OR' 1=1** & etc...
Finding out if SQL code is sanitizing post parameters.

Comment: I have seen html comments with actual server side code in them, and my rage was incredible. Anyway it is sooo rare it would hardly ever happen to you.